# Too much space under on-hold reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, design

[image]

What is all of that space for? There appear to be two break elements under the list, which is unnecessary, since the list already has a decent CSS margin under it.

Maybe it's just me, but it would look better if the break elements weren't there:

[image]

Comment: That looks like the correct shade of red, but your freehand circles seem to be very oddly shaped.

Comment: It's probably a fixed size block of reserved space of adequate length to accomodate custom close reasons.  In a flow-layout environment like a browser, you would think that the excess space could just be taken up automatically.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not sure what you mean. Still looks okay if we remove the `<br/>`s and add a couple more reasons: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hANEE.png

Comment: I mean the line breaks can't really reserve space for other elements, they take up extra space in addition to whatever else is in the containing element.

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: I love the free hand drawn with free hand.

Comment: OK, guys, closing a [status-completed] question as "no repro" is *very droll*, but let's get serious here. That's only for cases where the premise is no longer relevant… not for cases where the question did its job of triggering a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They seemed to be removed and the problem is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed):

[image]